# What was the purpose of this drain outlet and I would it be OK to floor over?

Tags: drain

Removed basement bathroom tiles and found a drain outlet which was tiled over. This bathroom is in the basement where we are adding laminate flooring. Was wondering why it is there and if it would be Ok to adding flooring over... or do I need to keep it accessible?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a cleanout (which means it probably should not have been tiled over)

You can get a dressier "flush cover" to allow access to it without being that much of an eyesore.

Comment: So I should NOT laminate over this ?

Comment: Probably laminate over, drill suitable hole and install nice cover. Or figure out where to drill/cut suitable hole, drill or saw it, and put that piece of laminate in. Cleanouts should be accessible.